# How can I acces data from a soql inner query in a lightning web component

Tags: javascript, salesforce, lwc

How can I access data from an inner query in lwc? Here's my code:

JS:

```
@wire(getProducts)
wiredProducts({error, data}){
    if(error){
        this.error = error;
    }else if(data){
        console.log(data);
        this.products = data;
        this.listprice = this.products.Product_Price_Entries__r.List_Price__c;
        console.log('ex'+listprice);
    }
}
```

Apex Controller:

```
public with sharing class ProductCatalogController  {
@AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
public static List<Product__c> getProductsList(){
    return [SELECT Id, Name, Store_Short_Description__c, Image__c, (SELECT List_Price__c FROM Product_Price_Entries__r)
            FROM Product__c
            WHERE Name != null
            WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
             Limit 10];
}
```

}

HTML:

```
                <template for:each={products} for:item="product">
                <div key={product.Id} class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-4">
                    <lightning-card class="cardBorder">
                        
                        <div class="slds-m-bottom_medium">
                            <lightning-formatted-number
                            value={products.listprice}
                            format-style="currency"> </lightning-formatted-number>
                        </div> 

                      
                    </lightning-card>
                </div>
            </template>
```

I'm trying to access the ListPrice value,
how can I accomplish this ?

Comment: If someone is able to help me, please write down your answers !

Comment: Is it the name after @wire? in the JS it is 'getProducts' but in the apex it is 'getProductsList'

Comment: @eaeaoo getProducts is the name I used when I imported the class, so that's not the issue

Comment: Shouldn't you have a for loop or array access in there? `this.products.Product_Price_Entries__r[0].List_Price__c`?

Comment: @FabioDelaCruz.could you check the relationship name from the lookup filed for example when you need to query contacts in inner query of account the relationship called contacts, other option is JS i case sensitive so please check how the API name is written.